# Loop variable forgotten when assigning it

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
myList = ['A','B','C']
for letter in myList:
    letter = myList
```

When running it I would expect variables to be assigned as following:

```
A = ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
B = ['A', 'B', 'C'] 
C = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Instead it seems that the loop is only assigning values to the "myList" component of the loop and forgetting to assign the anything for "letter". Hence the actual variable assignment looks like this:

```
letter = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Can someone please explain to me why python does not replace "letter" with values from "myList"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It DOES *replace "letter" with values from "myList"*: it put the value in the variable `letter`.

What it *doesn't* do is assign those values to a variable whose name is contained in `letter`, because that's not how assignment works